# Performance of a duplicate agregate function in a select query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a SQL query (in MySQL) that select a total and a count of how many completed task have the table:

```
SELECT
  count(*) as total, IF(SUM(NOT `completed`) IS NULL,0,SUM(NOT `completed`)) as incomplete
FROM
  tasks
```

The table can be made something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `clave` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'If it is 0 isn\'t completed, otherwise is completed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`clave`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You can observe that in the query I have used `SUM(NOT completed)` two times, one to check if it will return null (and return 0 instead) and one to return the count (when it isn't null). A `SUM()` function return `null` if the table (or query) is empty, namely the table have not row at all.

As you are trying to SUM two times, I think that MySQL will calculate the sum two times.

I have tested to try if I can set an alias for the column and then use it in a IF so mysql don't need to recalculate it.

And as a requirement, incomplete column must not be null in any circumstance (for example if the table tasks is empty).

And my question, **is this efficient? Will MySQL need to recalculate the sum each time or it remember it?**

Comment: Which column do you use to check for 'completed' or not 'completed'?

Comment: What has the query analyzer told you about your query so far? Try using `EXPLAIN` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: @JosephB `completed` is a column of table `tasks` of type boolean (tiny int).

Comment: @cfeduke I don't know how to use/interpret it.

Comment: Check the link in my first comment; I haven't ever had occasion to use MySQL's `EXPLAIN`, but it should be pretty apparent upon execution whether the aggregate function is happening twice, or just once with your query

Comment: @cfeduke Thanks for the link, I think that now I know what EXPLAIN do, but it explain what index and joins are used not what columns do.

Comment: I made quick test by adding like 10 times SUM function on same column, did not notice the difference in performance from only one SUM furnction. Maybe there was not much data. But query was running 0,5 second with one and 0,5 second with many, and running second time it was 0,05 s probably because of cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this may be a better way to do it because you do less calculations for **performance**

using the schema richard posted - see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e74b/5)

```
SELECT 
    total, 
    num_complete, 
    total - num_complete as num_incomplete
FROM(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as total,
        SUM(IF(t.completed > 0, 1, 0)) as num_complete
    FROM status_log t
) as t
```

---

checking for empty table per OP request

```
SELECT 
    total, 
    num_complete, 
    total - num_complete as num_incomplete
FROM(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as total,
        IF(COUNT(*) > 0, SUM(IF(t.completed > 0, 1, 0)), 0) as num_complete
    FROM status_log t
) as t
```

**you should do your check for null or empty table in another programming language** ... generally speaking SQL should be used to query from the table.. not when it is empty though... if it is completely empty then you should check for a null response when running this query in another programming language. that will improve the **performance** of it a lot.

Comment: Why would you use a subquery instead of CASE WHEN?

Comment: I didn't know what the data layout was when i wrote the answer - see timestamp - so i just provided a way to query off of the incomplete multiple times without computing `SUM` multiple times.. if i changed my answer it would just be copying others :)

Comment: With the second query you still have the problem of SUM returning null.

Comment: @PhoneixS yea I changed it from ` to '. I also added another query that would probably be best for performance if you want to try it and see if it runs faster.

Comment: @JohnRuddell this is a good shortcut based on an assumption of the data set you are working with. It is true that concepts like: Incomplete/Complete or Active/Inactive or On/Off have implicit paired values.  There is actually a third value which @PhoneixS mentions indirectly: Null.  For the statement `total - num_complete` to work, we would need to know if a `Null` value has any significance or if it is just a value that is ignored.

Comment: @RichardPascual thanks, your answer helped me understand how the data is laid out! I dont think NULL would be an issue as his table schema provided instantiates it as `not null default 0`

Comment: The null problem come from that if tasks table is empty, SUM() of no rows return Null.

Comment: @PhoneixS can you clarify what you mean by the tasks table being empty? your column has a NOT NULL constraint on the table and defaults to a 0,... so how does it have a null value in there?

Comment: @JohnRuddell not rows. For example, after it was created and `count(*)` return 0.

Comment: @PhoneixS ok i just edited my query.. it should solve that problem... if your table is empty, you shouldn't be querying off of it in the first place. but if you want a check for it then i added that :)

Comment: Interesting, you now duplicate `count(*)` instead of SUM, but I beliave that I have read something that MySQL remember the result of count(*) or that is calculated very efficiently so it will be an improvement.

Comment: Yea if your table is empty then you should't try to run this query in any case. are you doing this only in mysql? or querying from another programming language? you could also make another sub select if you wanted with the count(*) only once but the query starts to become unmanageable after two sub-selects.

Comment: `COUNT(*)`  will be an improvement regardless because doing the SUM() again not only does a SUM() but also an IF() check for every row that sets a value for you to then (subsequently) run a SUM off of :)

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency (or lack thereof) will have more to do with the indices present on the table, as well as the storage engine itself. Likewise, whether or not the result is stored in cache will have more to do with the storage engine than with the statement you are writing.

If I were writing this on an INNODB-based storage engine, I would do the following:

```
 SELECT   
       count(*) as total,    
       SUM(CASE WHEN completed = 0 OR completed IS NULL THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete 
 FROM tasks;
```

And I would index my "completed" column in order to do this.

The reason I would change from "IF" to case-when is largely just do the code-portability. CASE WHEN will be easier to move to other databases, if need be.

Also, an index on completed will allow this query to simply evaluate the index, the not the table value itself. That, with LRU, should give you plenty in the way of efficiency.

Comment: Richard's answer (above) added the inverse of incomplete... so SUM(CASE WHEN completed = 0 OR completed IS NULL THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomplete and SUM(CASE WHEN completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete. It's a nice touch. I'd add it if you have any reason to track that as well.

Comment: The `null` problem isn't in the `completed` column, it is in the `SUM()` function as if tasks is empty `SUM()` return `null`.

Comment: Without the details of the table it's awfully difficult to determine what the precise logic should be.... saw you edited and provided that. In light of table definition, just SUM(CASE WHEN completed > 0 then 1 else 0 END) as complete and SUM(CASE WHEN completed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as incomplete and move on. The key thing here is get an index on completed otherwise you're gonna have a table scan. You're on INNODB so LRU will help on the caching side. Index completed and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad question writing. I'm not very good explaining things. Still, SUM() will return NULL if the table is empty (have no row).

Comment: I'd handle that with PHP. Again, the biggest point I'd make here is index completed. If you don't and that table gets big, you're gonna have one heckuva slow query on your hands.

Comment: thats where I was going with the comments on my question... the query shouldn't be run if its empty.. if it is empty and the query is run then you should check in another programming language (wich ever the OP is using) for either a null value or a 0 or a number > 0 for all intents and purposes

Comment: Dont forget to accept an answer! I don't really care if you dont accept mine.. but its not a good practice to ask a question and then not accept an answer :)

Comment: In my real problem I have made the check in php but I will add an index as all you point to. @JohnRuddell It could be good if you include your comment as part of your answer. Yes, I will accept an answer, I simply given a little more time.

Comment: To be specific, this "if it is empty and the query is run then you should check in another programming language (wich ever the OP is using) for either a null value or a 0 or a number > 0 for all intents and purposes"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a `CASE` statement.  You can get both aggregate values from a single SQL statement.  The second query example shows how the `CASE` statement can get you a pivoted output compared to a direct aggregation query statement:

```
[SQL Fiddle][1]
```

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE status_log 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     type varchar(20), 
     status varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO status_log
(type, status)
VALUES
('Alpha', 'COMPLETE'),
('Bravo', 'INCOMPLETE'),
('Charlie', 'INCOMPLETE'),
('Delta', 'COMPLETE'),
('Echo', 'COMPLETE'),
('Foxtrot', 'INCOMPLETE'),
('Golf', 'COMPLETE'),
('Hotel', 'COMPLETE')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT count(1) as count_by_status, status
  FROM status_log
 GROUP BY status
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1a60c/3/0)**:

```
| COUNT_BY_STATUS |     STATUS |
|-----------------|------------|
|               5 |   COMPLETE |
|               3 | INCOMPLETE |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_count, 
  sum(case when status = 'COMPLETE' then 1
           else 0 end) as completed_count,
  sum(case when status = 'INCOMPLETE' then 1
           else 0 end) as incomplete_count
  FROM status_log
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1a60c/3/1)**:

```
| TOTAL_COUNT | COMPLETED_COUNT | INCOMPLETE_COUNT |
|-------------|-----------------|------------------|
|           8 |               5 |                3 |
```

Comment: Yep. I like Richard's solution far better (props Richard for adding Completed_count as well. I should have done that too). I would still add an index on status. That'll help you avoid a table scan.

Comment: The problem is that you are still using SUM() that return a null if the table have not rows.

Comment: Also note that I want to know if MySQL need to recalculate the column value for that duplicated expresions.

Comment: Phoneix: The answer to whether or not MySQL will need to recalculate the column value is actually not the most important question here. And by the way, that answer is "maybe" and it will depend on a lot more things than we can dive into here.  Whether or not your query would recalculate or not is not actually the most important question to ask here.  More inexpensive calculations are not nearly as problematic as fewer expensive ones. Get an index on completed and it won't matter if it has to recalculate it or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you make it into an inline view, you can select multiple times from the query, as below:

```
SELECT total, incomplete, incomplete
FROM
(
SELECT
  count(*) as total, IF(SUM(NOT `completed`) IS NULL,0,SUM(NOT `completed`)) as incomplete
FROM
  tasks
) incomplete_count;
```

If you selected from a sub-query or an inline view multiple times, then MySQL does not have to re-calculate it. Also, you can perform any additional operations / filters in the outer query.

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly.. this is not what the OP was asking for

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you for feedback. I have added a brief explanation.

Comment: anytime :) in your sub select you are doing `SUM(NOT completed)` twice.. the OP was asking if that is efficient and or if its possible to not do it twice. look at my answer.

Comment: @JosephB Yes, see John Ruddell answer. You are still duplicating the SUM(...) statement so you have translated the problem to the subquery.

Comment: the way this answer is written and your original query @PhoneixS mysql would be calculating the sum for each time you write it, and it does not store the info for reuse, unless you add an alias and query off of that alias

Comment: Thanks for info about how its calculated (better add it to the answer). I tried to make an alias like `SUM(...) as num, IF(IS NULL num, 0, num) as incompleted` but raised an error.

Comment: thats because you need to say `IF(num is null, 0, num)`

Comment: No, I have tried it but the same problem `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'num' in 'field list'`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to John Ruddell and PhoneixS for clarifications. Here's a version using CASE WHEN:

```
select 
  count(*),
  sum(
   case completed
    when 1 then 1 
    else 0
   end) 'completed',
  sum(
   case when completed is null then 1 
    else 0
   end) 'incomplete'
from tasks;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7437b/3)</kbd>